# Create a post from every image in my media gallery

Tags: images, uploads, media-library

I'm looking for a good way to create posts from every image in my media image gallery. I've uploaded about 200 pictures and want to create a post for each picture, where I set the picture as a thumbnail.

I'm using the Photogram Theme and just want to show some pictures (title and other stuff not required).

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: What do you exactly mean? Each image uploaded to Wordpress through the media manager (or using the media manager API) actually has its own post (attachment post type). Even it can has its own template (image.php under your theme folder).

Answer (score 3):

If you have the image in your media library you can just loop trough them and create post via `wp_insert_post`.

```
function import_post_from_imgs() {
  $images = get_posts('post_type=attachment&post_status=inherit&posts_per_page=-1');
  // just a minimal security check
  if ( ! current_user_can('publish_posts') ) return;
  if ( ! empty($images) ) { foreach ( $images as $image) {
    // prevent duplicate if for some reason the function is called more than once
    if ( get_post_meta($image->ID, '_imported', true) ) continue;
    $post = array(
      'post_title' => $image->post_title,
      'post_content' => '',
      'post_content' => 'publish'
    );
    // insert post
    $postid = wp_insert_post( $post );
    if ( $postid ) {
      // set the image as thumbnalil
      set_post_thumbnail($postid, $image->ID);
      update_post_meta($image->ID, '_imported', 1);
    }
  } }
}

function go_import_post_from_imgs() {
  if ( isset($_GET['import_images']) ) import_post_from_imgs();
}

add_action('admin_init', 'go_import_post_from_imgs');
```

In code above the import function is triggered on admin init, when the `$_GET` variable 'import_images' is setted.

So, you have to login into your dashboard and then the url of your page is sonething like `http://example.com/wp-admin/`. Now jus manually add '?import_images=1' so your url became `http://example.com/wp-admin/?import_images=1` and hit *Enter*.

After some seconds you should see the posts created from images.

Be aware that this function cretae a post from all images you have updated. If you want exclude some images, you can take 2 ways:

1. look for the IDs of the images you want to exclude and add this 2 lines:

   ```
   $exclude = array(12, 256, 587); // the ids you want to skip
   if ( in_array($image->ID, $exclude) ) continue;
   ```

   before `if ( get_post_meta($image->ID, '_imported', true) ) continue;`
2. Previous method is good if you want to exclude a little number of images, if you want to exclude more, you can [register a custom taxonomy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy) for the attachments and assign a particular term to images you want to skip (e.g. 'skip'). *(For these tasks a read [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/112078/bulk-term-assignment-for-attachment-taxonomies) can help you)*. After that, Assuming you taxonomy is called 'media-tag' and you have added the 'skip' term to the images you want to skip, add this line at same place:

   ```
    if ( has_term('skip', 'media-tag', $image->ID) ) continue;
   ```