# How to get post bulk edit action trigger and get edited post ids?

Tags: posts, plugin-development, save-post, quick-edit

I want to send email if a postmeta of a post is changed to the expected value.So previously i was doing loop to check the post meta in each post. In here am running the loop in `admin_init` hook. But this slow down the site, so i'm thinking to do this on save post only. SO the edited post may have the meta value am expecting then i'll send the mail.

Previous

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {

    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        if(get_post_meta($the_query->post->ID,'custom_post_meta',true)=='ok'){
        //mail() function goes here
        }
    }

} 

wp_reset_postdata();
```

This is unwanted because only certain post may be edited. Blindly checking post meta with a loop every time is waste.

So i thought to use on `save_post` on save we'll check whether the post meta is changed to the expected value then we'll do the mail.like below

```
function testing($post_id){
    if(get_post_meta($the_query->post->ID,'send_mail',true)=='ok'){
        //mail() function goes here
        }
        //only for edited post alone i'm checking here
}

add_action('save_post','testing');
```

There are another two scenario where the post meta may be changed which are **bulk edit** and **quick edit**

For quick edit i found this

```
function check(){
var_dump($_REQUEST);//can able to get the post id, i can do the rest
}
add_action('check_ajax_referer','check');
```

But for bulk edit i don't have any clue. I tried searching, In [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/41700/how-to-implement-bulk-actions-in-my-plugin#answer-41721) i found that `$_REQUEST` may contain `action` and `postid`. So i thought for bulk edit there might be an action in `$_REQUEST['action']` but i couldn't find when i try like this

```
function another_check(){
var_dump($REQUEST['action']);
}

add_action('admin_init','another_check');
```

I found this `check_admin_referer` too but i couldn't able to figure out as it does not print when i var dump. Will this(`check_admin_referer`) work or suit on this? Is there any other easy way to get the edited post ids?

**How can i get the List of post id on bulk edit?** From then i can able to do the check and send mail accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your problem is:

> I want to send email if a postmeta of a post is changed to the
>   expected value

Why do yous ask for:

> How can i get the List of post id on bulk edit?

This is a typical [x/y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): when you have a problem, ask how to solve that problem, instead of asking ways to apply what *you think* is the solution...

Going in the details, you want to perform an action when a meta field is updated? Why don't just look at.. the moment it is updated?

Everytime a post meta is updated, WordPress call the hook `'updated_postmeta'` like so

[`do_action("updated_{$type}_meta", $meta_id, $object_id, $meta_key, $meta_value);`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.1/src/wp-includes/meta.php#L160)

where `$type` is `'post'`.

As you can see, you have enough informations to do anything you want.

Let's assume you want to send a mail to the post author everytime the meta 'send_mail' is set to 'ok':

```
add_action( 'updated_post_meta', 'listen_to_meta_change', 20, 4 );

function listen_to_meta_change( $mid, $pid, $key, $value ) {
  if ( $key !== 'send_mail' ) return; // if the key is not the right one do nothing
  $value = maybe_unserialize( $value );
  if ( $value !== 'on' ) return; // if the value is not the right one do nothing
  // if we're here, the post meta 'send_mail' was set to 'on' for a post, let's get it
  $post = get_post( $pid );
  if ( $post->post_type !== 'post' ) return; // maybe check for a specific post type?
  $recipient = new WP_User( $post->post_author ); // get the post author
  if ( ! $recipient->exists() ) return; // check if is a valid user

  static $sended = array();
  if ( ! isset($sended[$recipient->ID]) ) $sended[$recipient->ID] = array();
  if ( isset($sended[$recipient->ID][$pid]) ) {
    // already sent email for this user & post & request: that's enough, let's exit
    return;
  }
  $sended[$recipient->ID][] = $pid;

  // ok, send the email, you can write the function, by yourself, isn't it?
  // be sure to have control on how many emails you send to an user:
  // too much emails slow down your site and also make you a spammer...
  // probably you can take control that using an user meta...
  send_email_to_user_when_meta_updated( $recipient );
}
```

Note that this code runs only when a meta is *updated*, and not when is *added*.

To run same code when the meta is also added, just add another action:

```
add_action( 'added_post_meta', 'listen_to_meta_change', 20, 4 );
```

Both hooks work in identical way, passing identical arguments, so no problem on using same function for both.

Comment: Thanks.Looks you are targeting exactly. But it is not working on bulk edit and quick edit. Why am i talking about bulk and quick edit because on bulk and quick edit this post meta may change, at this point also we need to check and perform action. But the function am hooking is not happening on bulk,quick edit. It works only on update the product from single product page. Am trying this in woocommerce. Does it makes any sense? @G.M.

Comment: @sun How do you edit post meta on bulk edit?

Comment: Select the products then edit, In there changing the Visibility or Tax Status in select boxes and then hit update

Comment: @sun visibility and taxomomy are **not** post meta

Comment: I just showed them for example purpose. lets take price or stock for example.  stock('_stock_status') is a post meta, i think. Check this [link](http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Product.html#220) Where its check whether post meta(`_stock_status`) is updated or not. Let me know if this(`_stock_status`) is not post meta.

Comment: i don't know why it is not triggering the `updated_post_meta` for the `_stock_status` but overall your concept is really nice and helpful to me. I also found this trigger in [here](http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Admin_CPT_Product.html#983) so after they save in their way i can able to check the thing i am looking for then hook my functions. It will be nice if i know why it is not triggering the `updated_post_meta` for `_stock_status` post meta. Thanks

Comment: @sun It **is** triggering, but if you look my code, the line `if ( $key !== 'send_mail' ) return;` make function work only if the key is 'send_mail'. So when '_stock_status' is updated the function is triggered but does nothing. To make it works for `_stock_status` or other meta keys, change that line in: `if ( ! in_array( $key, array('send_mail', '_stock_status', '_sky', 'anothe-key-here', 'and-so-on') ) ) return;`